# Is it required to migrate to GIS when you're using google-oauth2?

Tags: google-oauth

This link https://developers.googleblog.com/2022/03/gis-jsweb-authz-migration.html says

> Your full suite of apps and platforms may be using different methods of authentication and authorization from Google. The following are NOT affected by this deprecation announcement:
>
> Android or iOS native app SDKs,
> **Backend platforms directly calling Google’s OAuth 2.0 or OpenID services.**

I'm currently trying to understand our huge legacy code which might be affected by the GIS migration. Currently, we just redirect to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth to start the oauth2 process, once the user clicks the "Sign in with google" button. I've seen this link in the example of the old way from the migration document here: https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis#oauth-2.0-endpoints however I'm not sure if it is required to migrate to GIS or not.

From what I understand, only the frontend related libraries should be worried, but I'm dumb so maybe I'm misunderstanding. Can anyone help enlighten me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to migrate if you are directly making calls to the Google's OAuth 2.0 endpoints.

The guide you reference recommends using the library with the note *use the Google Identity Services library to support a less intrusive popup UX mode and to avoid having to manage complex OAuth 2.0 requests and responses*. The intent there is to simplify your implementation not to force a migration.